# Python3 / Creating multiple class objects with different arguments from a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, class

I want to create instances of my class car. How do I put the arguments from the list for each of the x amount of cars?

```
argument_list = ['h','2','2','0','v','2','0','0'........etc]

car1 = car('h','2','2','0')
car2 = car('v','2','0','0')
car3 = car(............etc)
```

doing this for every single car would be so bad:

```
car1 = car(*coordinate_list[0:4])
car2 = car(*coordinate_list[4:8])
```

Comment: Do you need your car objects to be `car1`, `car2`, `car3` or can they be a list of car objects such as `car = []` , `car[0] = car('h'...)`? Because if so, then you can very simply use a for loop.

Comment: I need it exactly as shown.. NOT a list

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done with a for loop and globals.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        self.attr1 = args[0]
        self.attr2 = args[1]
        self.attr3 = args[2]
        self.attr4 = args[3]

argument_list = list(range(32)) #enough arguments for 8 cars

# the // operator guarantees integer division
num_cars = len(argument_list)//4 
car_list = []
for i in range(num_cars-1):
    # [i*4:(i+1)*4] will grab 4 items at a time from argument list
    # the asterisk before it *argument_list[i*4:(i+1)*4] unpacks the list so they can be arguments for init  
    car_list.append(Car(*argument_list[i*4:(i+1)*4]))


for car in car_list:
    print(car.attr1, car.attr2, car.attr3, car.attr4)


for i, car in enumerate(car_list):
    # accesses global variables and adds whatever variable we want by name
    globals()['car' + str(i)] = car 

print(car1.attr1)

print(car2.attr2)
```

[image]

Comment: The OP said explicitly that s/he needs it with the variables as shown, not a list.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see that before.